# Create an object array of class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a class object array like this for "CruiseServerHttpClient" class

```
private CruiseServerHttpClient[] _cruiseManager;

for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
_cruiseManager[i]=new CruiseServerHttpClient();
}
```

Is this the right way to create the object. I get Null reference exception on the new keyword.

BTW, I'm using VS 2010.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the `_cruiseManager` array before setting its elements inside the loop:

```
_cruiseManager = new CruiseServerHttpClient[2];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    _cruiseManager[i] = new CruiseServerHttpClient();
}
```

Comment: Better to use List<CruiseServerHttpClient> instead.

Answer (score 1):

List _cruiseManager=new List ();

_cruiseManager.Add(new CruiseServerHttpClient());

_cruiseManager.Add(new CruiseServerHttpClient());

this will do.